# Adding a constraint to both tables independently in join

Tags: mysql, constraints

I am trying to create a SELECT statement from two different tables, where I use to send messages, I don't want to send a message to someone for 1 wk after they join, however if I have already sent them a message I want to wait 10 days before sending next one.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT c.*, g.resToMeeting, g.replied, g.conlevel, g.coffee, g.lastMessageSent 
FROM connections c
INNER JOIN groupmembers g
ON c.Id=g.Id 
AND g.groupN=244 # this decides the client I'm pulling for...(or group they own)
AND g.client=c.client
AND g.conlevel=1
AND (datediff(curdate(), g.lastMessageSent) > 10 OR datediff(curdate(), c.dateConnected) > 7)
AND c.validated=1 
AND c.process_rank=0 
ORDER BY c.dateAdded ASC
LIMIT 0, 200
```

The trouble I'm having is that it shows EITHER people who haven't joined within the last week, OR people who haven't received a messages within the last 10 days. It seems that it isn't working:

I received a record that had lastMessageSent as 2015-04-29, (which isn't 10 days ago) but the dateConnected was 2015-04-15 which was over 7 days. How can I enforce both rules "together" not either or, sometimes there is no data in lastMessageSent or dateConnected, and that should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the `ON` clause should say how the tables are connected.

After that, you have a `WHERE` clause that lists whatever filtering you need for any of the tables.

I suspect you should have had:

... `INNER JOIN groupmembers g`
  `ON c.Id=g.Id`
**WHERE** `g.groupN=244` ...

**Edit**

I think you want this, not `XOR`:

```
AND g.lastMessageSent < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY -- Avoid frequent spamming
AND c.dateConnected < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY -- Wait a while before first message
```

Note that I reforumlated the comparisions -- it is always good to have the column on one side and a constant on the other.  This allows for the possibility of using an INDEX; hiding the column inside `DATEDIFF()` does not.

`CURDATE` counts back from midnight this morning; `NOW` counts back from this second.  (You pick; I am merely suggesting an alternative.)

Caution:  If "no message ever sent" is stored as `NULL` in `g.lastMessageSent`, then the above will be `false`.  So perhaps you need

```
AND ( g.lastMessageSent IS NULL
   OR g.lastMessageSent < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY ) -- Avoid frequent spamming
AND c.dateConnected < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY -- Wait a while before first message
```

"Either..or", in my understanding, is `OR`.  "Either, but not both" is `XOR`.

Comment: Thanks Rick! I think that is exactly what I want, interesting info on the datediff Now comparison too. Haha! I just noticed your comments in the Sql, ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"EITHER" is an XOR. i.e. (A and not B) or (not A and B), so change this condition

`AND (datediff(curdate(), g.lastMessageSent) > 10 OR datediff(curdate(), c.dateConnected) > 7)`

To

`AND ( ((datediff(curdate(), g.lastMessageSent) > 10 AND datediff(curdate(), c.dateConnected) < 7)) OR ((datediff(curdate(), g.lastMessageSent) < 10 AND datediff(curdate(), c.dateConnected) > 7)) )`

Note that instead of using `NOT`, I inverted the condition.

### EDIT

Since MySQL has `XOR` operator, it is possible to rewrite the line as:

`AND (datediff(curdate(), g.lastMessageSent) > 10 XOR datediff(curdate(), c.dateConnected) > 7)`

Answer (score 0):

Why can you just change:

```
AND (datediff(curdate(), g.lastMessageSent) > 10 OR datediff(curdate(),     c.dateConnected) > 7)
```

to:

```
AND datediff(curdate(), g.lastMessageSent) > 10 
AND datediff(curdate(), c.dateConnected) > 7
```

Comment: This will exclude the people who have not received any message yet, for example.

Comment: Ah.. I missed that. Your solution will work and I think you can simplify it further by taking his original line of code and just change the OR to XOR.

Comment: Right, I implemented XOR, while it is actually provided by MySQL. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Jehad (and everyone else) I didn't know mySql had an XOR operator, nor did I know the correct syntax after the "ON".

Unfortunately it doesn't work, it doesn't include people who had never had a message, all the results have either a lastMessageSent field OR NOT ONE BUT a dateConnected field populated. There are no results with null values for either field.